# How To Fix Overlapping Partitions

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive, ssd

I am currently trying to move all of the data from  my 120gb SSD to my 500gb HDD. I am doing this using clonezilla, however every time I try it fails, saying that it cannot have overlapping partitions. I can not figure out which partitions are overlapping, or how I would fix this issue. Here is my partition table:

```
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          8192 234455039 234446848 111.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1050624   2101247   1050624   513M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda3       2103294 234452991 232349698 110.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       2103296 234452991 232349696 110.8G 83 Linux
```

If anyone knows how I would fix this issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cloning from an SSD to HDD (or vice versa) can result in some issues as the two storage devices handle partitions and alignment differently. Rather than clone, would it not be possible to install fresh on the HDD, install the applications you need, then copy the data over from the SSD? 

Comment: I would try copy/paste of partitions using GParted. I’ve never needed to do this so you may hit the same problem but it may enable you to achieve your goal

Comment: Can you give more details about exactly how you are using Clonezilla? When in the process are you enlarging the partitions? Are you cloning the whole disk, or one partition at a time? Which ever you are doing, try the other. Whole disk is likely easier, then enlarge.

Comment: Is the partition table supplied of the SSD?  sda1 overlaps everything else, I'd expect it to end before the start of sda2.  Backup what you can, the thing may easily get messed up even worse.

Comment: Unfortunately, using Gparted did not work, also due to the overlapping partitions. When using clonezilla, I was directly cloning to the HDD, however because clonezilla uses parted, it does not allow anything to work in clonezilla because of overlapping partitions. I do not know how the partitions overlapped, I have not touched the partitions and I assume it happened when I first installed. Thank you for the help.